# pands.read_json dtype object to integer/numerics

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tring to convert a JSON string into a pandas dataframe. While `pandas.read_json` can infer the data type if there's no "missing value" (as in blanks or 'NA'), it'll classify the column as dtype `object` if there's a blank in the value.

For example:

```
d1 = {"a":"1","b":"2"}
d2 = {"a":"","b":""}
l = [d1,d2]
l_js = json.dumps(l)
d = pd.read_json(l_js)
d.dtypes
```

It'll return dtype object for both columns/dictionary object.

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to do this without having to loop through each dictionary in the list.

Answer (score 0):

there seems to be no specific parameter within the `pd.read_json()` function to deal with this kind of situation, because there dictionary `d2` has the value `''`. However, this could be dealt with in this particular case with a `replace` followed by a loop that would convert the column into floats.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np
d1 = {"a":"1","b":"2"}
d2 = {"a":"","b":""}
l = [d1,d2]
l_js = json.dumps(l)
d = pd.read_json(l_js).replace('',np.nan)
for i in d:
    d[i] = d[i].astype(float)
print(d.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
a    float64
b    float64
dtype: object
```

Of course, if you are not sure if all columns should be float, or some are okay as objects, then you can simply add a `try`/`except` after the `for`:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import numpy as np
d1 = {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"aaa"}
d2 = {"a":"","b":"","c":"ccc"}
l = [d1,d2]
l_js = json.dumps(l)
d = pd.read_json(l_js).replace('',np.nan)
for i in d:
    try:
        d[i] = d[i].astype(float)
    except ValueError:
        pass
print(d.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
a    float64
b    float64
c     object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out,for `pandas.read_json` it requires the string to be null for that part, like so:
`'[{"a": "1", "b": "2"}, {"a": null, "b": null}, {"a": null, "b": null}]'`

So to do that, you can replace the string part of "" to 'null:

```
l_js.replace('""','null')
```